How to execute a formula in a separate sheet referenced by another cell within the current sheet in Microsoft excel
I have a product that I have been building that requires the user to build new sheets in the workbook for separate people. Due to not knowing the names, I have the future sheets numbered in a cell that will refer to the future sheet named by numbers (1-50) using the “=IF(ISERROR(INDIRECT(“ formula I can reference specific cells in that future sheet when it is created which is great for many of the items I need but the most important formula I need to execute in future sheet “1” named in cell A1 for example is “=INDEX(A1!$B$11:B380,MATCH(H$4,A1!$A:$A380,0),0)”. This formula gives a “#VALUE!” Error due to the A1 sheet name reference. When hard coded as ‘1’! It works for sheets that already exist but not the future sheets that are created which is what I need. I am not sure how to integrate the needed formula into the “=IF(ISERROR(INDIRECT(“ formula to get the desired result. Please help!

Try putting the ranges you want to reference inside INDIRECT; something like: =INDEX(Indirect(A1&"!B11:B380"),MATCH(H$4,indirect(A1&"!A11:A380"),0),0)

You can use one of the following formulas:
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($A$1&"!B11:B380"),MATCH(H$4,INDIRECT($A$1&"!A11:A380"),0)),0)
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H$4,INDIRECT($A$1&"!A11:B380"),2,FALSE),0)

Addresses must be written down carefully. They have to match each other.

